# hdfs-site.xml for adding a new datanode

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop 2.7.2 in pseudo-distributed mode(machine-1).I want to add a new datanode to it to make it as a cluster.As, but the problem is both of the machine has differnet disk partitions.

I installed same version hadoop 2.7.2 in new data node(machine-2) and also can ssh with machine-1.After googling many websites, all have common tutorials mentioning that, we have to have the same configurations files inside `/etc/hadoop/` folder.

With the above said, my existing configurations in machine-1  are:

**core-site.xml**

```
    <configuration>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
                <value>/home1/tmp</value>
                <description>A base for other temporary directories
```

```
    <property>
                <name>fs.default.name</name>
                <value>hdfs://CP000187:9000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.vasanth.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
     </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.vasanth.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
     <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
     </property>
     <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
            <value>file:/home1/hadoop_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
     </property>
     <property>
            <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
            <value>file:/home1/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
     </property>
     <property>
            <name>dfs.permissions</name>
            <value>false</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

> `/home1` is a disk mounted in machine1.
>
> Machine-2 has two disk mounted namely /hdd1 and /hdd2.

Now, what should i specify in `hdfs-site.xml` on the new machine(machine-2) to make use of both hdd1 and hdd2?

should the value of `dfs.data.dir` of all nodes needs to be same?

Is the `dfs.namenode.name.dir` property required on `hdfs-site.xml` on machine2(since it is not a name node)?

My simplified question is it mandatory to replicate the master node configuration files in slave nodes also? Please help me out on this..

Answer (score 1):

You just need to copy entire hadoop folder from node1 to node2 . So in both configuration should point hdfs://CP000187:9000 . You dont have to do any addition settings in node2 .

To start datanode in node2 run (From sbin) .You need run only datanode and nodemanager process in node2

```
./hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
```

To check whether datanode is added correct or not , run dfsadmin -report in node1

```
hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

Output :

```
Configured Capacity: 24929796096 (23.22 GB)
Present Capacity: 17852575744 (16.63 GB)
DFS Remaining: 17851076608 (16.63 GB)
DFS Used: 1499136 (1.43 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.01%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (2):
```

Comment: my masternode data directory is different and new nodes data directory is different.How does it know where to store data, if i simply copy files?

Comment: then edit dfs.datanode.data.dir  in  hdfs-site.xml  to the specific location in node2 . All communication between namenode and datanode are based on ports. not based on the file system

Comment: hadoopp-daemon.sh is deprecated. use ```hdfs --daemon start datanode``` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To add datanode check below

1. Copy `core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-site.xml and hadoop-env.sh` files to new machine hadoop dir
2. Add ip address or hostname in /etc/hosts
3. Add ip address of the new datanode in `slaves file` (located in `/etc/hadoop/`)
4. As you mentioned you have 2 hdd, mention those locations in `hdfs-site.xml` file like below
   `<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir<name>
   <property>/hdd1,/hdd2<property>`
5. Restart the services

Comment: In your 4th step should i modify hdfs-site.xml on both machines?.if so, the master noder cannot recoginize such folder since it is a local path

Comment: You have to mention where the locations are available (new machine)

Comment: so i have to give /home1 in master node hdfs-site.xml and /hdd1,/hdd2 in new node hdfs-site.xml for dfs.data.dir?

Comment: In hadoop 3.0 slaves file has been renamed to etc/hadoop/workers.